# Apache LocationMatch authorize all subpaths PHP

Tags: php, apache, authorization

We have a PHP site:

site.com

We want all subpaths from the root to require basic authentication.  e.g.

site.com - no authentication required

site.com/subpath requires authentication

We have this directive:

```
<LocationMatch "^/.+$">

  AuthName "members Only"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/auth-pass-file
  Require valid-user
 </LocationMatch>
```

However it is asking for a password when we go to http://site.com/ or http://site.com.

Can someone suggest a solution so that authorization only is asked for sub paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We added specific directories to check (ones that exist) and created an error redirect when people tried to fish for non-existent pages.

Answer (score 0):

`<LocationMatch "^/.*/.+$">` should work. Your LocationMatch is actually selecting everything in the root directory, you need to go one level down.

Answer (score 0):

Because authz rules are applied not only to the actually-requested /, but also to what that expands to -- such as /index.html

You need to allow that separately, unfortunately...